# unable to update other cells from rendered cell ag-grid react

Tags: reactjs, html-table, ag-grid

I am developing an react app, and using ag-grid for table creation. In the table, I have 3 columns (name, status, submit). status and submit columns uses cell renderer (since it holds icons inside the cell). As per my need, the following steps needs to be done once the submit button (cell:3) is clicked:

- step:1 I need to initiate the API call
- step:2 update the status field (cell:2)

I am able to achieve the step:1, however I have stuck on step:2. It will be helpfull if there is a solution in ag-grid to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use cellRenderer property in columnDefs to update the cell as per the prefrence

```
columnDefs: [
          {
            headerName: "Name", field: "name"
          },
          {
            headerName: "Status", field: "Status"
            cellRenderer: (params) => {
              if (params && params.value === 'Pass') {
                return '<h1>'+params.value+'</h1>'
              }
              if (params && params.value === 'Fail') {
                return '<h6>'+params.value+'</h6>''
              }
            }
          }
        ],
```